# tornado PeriodicCallback: provide callback with arguments?

Tags: python, tornado

the function `tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(callback, callback_time, io_loop=None)` says I couldn't add arguments for my `callback` function, but what if I really need to call `callback` with arguments? Is there a work around?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, use a lambda or functools.partial. Docs for the partial function are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

```
from tornado import ioloop

def my_function(a, b):
    print a, b

x = 1
y = 2 

periodic_callback = PeriodicCallback(
    lambda: my_function(x, y),
    10)

ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

In this example, if you change x or y, the change will be reflected in the next call to "my_function". On the other hand if you "import functools" and:

```
periodic_callback = PeriodicCallback(
    functools.partial(my_function, x, y),
    10)
```

Then later changes to the value of x and y will *not* appear in "my_function". And finally, you could just do:

```
def my_partial():
    my_function(x, y)

periodic_callback = PeriodicCallback(
    my_partial,
    10)
```

This behaves the same as the "lambda" expression earlier.